# Finding the roots, with multiplicity, of a polynomial with compound angle formula

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots

My question is to find the roots, counted with multiplicity, of the polynomial equation

$16x^5-20x^3+5x-1=0$ using the compound angle formula $\sin\left(5\theta\right)=16\sin^5\theta-20\sin^3\theta+5\sin\theta$

So after substituting $x=\sin\theta$, I get to the equation

$\sin(5\theta)=1$

Then I get an infinitude of $\theta$ values, which when I find the sines of these values, all correspond to the distinct solutions $x=1,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(-\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)$.

What I don't understand is how I can then find which roots are repeating, since the degree of the polynomial is 5 hence there must be 5 roots when counted with multiplicity.

Also if possible, is there a way to solve this polynomial using the given compound angle formula without the need to find the distinct roots and then determine the ones which repeat?

This is because the solutions to this question say $x=1,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{9\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{17\pi}{10}\right)$ without any reasoning, which makes me suspect I am unaware of some related theorem.

Comment: Is your first equation correct? Maybe it is $16x^ 5$  instead of $x^5$.

Comment: Technically speaking, $x=\sin \theta $ is not a correct and proper substitution  since it makes an assumption that $x \in [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, the solutions are:
$$x=1,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{9\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{17\pi}{10}\right)$$ 
Because,
$$\sin(5\theta)=1 \Rightarrow \theta=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)$$
and setting $k=0,1,2,3,4$ we get all five solutions.

But $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{9\pi}{10}\right)$ and $\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{10}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{17\pi}{10}\right)$.

So the five roots (with multiplicity) are
$$1,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{10}\right)$$.

Let's explain better why if make any other choice of $k$ we will always find an angle congruent to one of those in $S=\{\pi/10,\pi/2,9\pi/10,13\pi/10,17\pi/10\}$.

We can write $k=5n+r$ with $r \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $n \in \Bbb Z$. Replacing that at the expression of $\theta$ we get:

$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{2k\pi}{5}=\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{2(5n+r)\pi}{5}=\frac{\pi}{10}+2n\pi+\frac{2r\pi}{5} \equiv \frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{2r\pi}{5} $$

The last equivalence means that the angle $\frac{\pi}{10}+2n\pi$ is congruent to $\frac{\pi}{10}$. That means that both angle stop at the same point on the trigonometric circle and then if we apply any trigonometric function at those angles we will get the same value. The algebric value are different but geometricaly they represent the same point at the circle.

It means that if we want to find the different solution for $\sin\theta$ is enough to take

$$\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{2r\pi}{5}$$

with $r=0,1,2,3,4$.

Comment: The question seems to be more like: **why** the specific values of $k=0,1,2,3,4$? Why not $k=-2,-1,1,2,5$?

Comment: When we choose $k=0,1,2,3,4$ we get all different values of $\theta$, wich are $S={\pi/10,\pi/2,9\pi/10,13\pi/10,17\pi/10}$. If you those any other set for $k$ your new set will be inside $S$.

Comment: What do you mean by "different values of $\theta$"? If we choose different $k$, then obviously the $\theta$'s obtained will be different. And then, how can the new set of $\theta$'s be "inside" the aforementioned set $S$.

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento could you please clarify what you meant by 'your new set will be inside S'?

Comment: Note that if  $k \in \mathbb{Z}, \ \mbox{with}\ k \neq 0,1,2,3$  or  $4 $ then $k = 5\cdot n + r$ with $r=0,1,2,3\  \mbox{or}\    4, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. In this case this does not matter because $sin (\frac{1}{5}( \frac{\pi}{2} + 2kpi )) = sin (\frac{1}{5}( \frac{\pi}{2} + 2rpi ))$.

Comment: @Rishi:I just wrote a more complete solution. Please let me know if now is clear.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat  made a good remark. The solution is correct for  $x\in[-1,1]$. But does not proof that they are the only roots, since they are not differents.  Maybe  a way to solve this problem is to show that the first derivative of  $p(x)= 16x^5-20x^3 + 5x -1 $  is positive for $x>1$ and $x<-1$, in this case $p(x)$ is increasing: $p(x)\geq p(1)$ for $x>1$ and $p(x)\leq p(-1)$ for $x<-1$. Probably will need some ajustements because the result does not garantee that the function is strictly increasing.

Comment: @PryscillaSilva: I don't think that the remark is right. We found 5 solutions for the equation $16x^5-20x^3+5x-1=0$ and the Fundamental Algebra Theorem garantee that there are no more roots.

Comment: Well, I think is not correct because you find three solutions, of course if you know that the roots are only in $[-1,1]$ that is enough . Or if you proof that the sum of the multiplicities of the roots is five, in this case in fact the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra garantee they are the unique solutions.

Comment: Nope. I found five: $1,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{10}\right),\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{10}\right)$

Comment: Okay, my problem is that in your solution I can't find where you prove that the other two roots are of multiplicity two. Since the solution is give in terms of sin and not in terms of angles.

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento sorry I don't think you understood the point of my question. My point wasn't to just find the different roots to this equation, but also which roots are repeated. e.g. why is sin(pi/10) repeated twice and not thrice?

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is how I can then find which roots are repeating, since the degree of the polynomial is 5 hence there must be 5 roots when counted with multiplicity.

If one **knows** the roots, then it is possible to find their multiplicity by finding whether or not the function's derivative(s) have the same root. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593568/multiple-root-of-a-polynomial-is-also-a-root-of-the-derivative) for a proof.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that theorem, but how exactly does one figure out if any of those three distinct roots are zeros of the derivative polynomial?

Comment: The derivative polynomial is $80x^4 - 60x^2 + 5$. So you know that $1$ definitely is not a repeated root. Also, you can see that the derivative is even. So it has $2$ positive roots and $2$ negative roots. And you have figured out that the distinct roots of the original equation are definitely $\sin(\frac{\pi}{10})$ and $\sin(\frac{-3\pi}{10})$. Do you see a complete argument?