# Relation between polynomial division and derivative

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, polynomials

> $P(x)$ is a polynomial and it is equal to $2x^3 + 2ax^2 +bx +c$ . It is given that $P(x)$ can be divided by $(x-1)^3$ with zero remainder. Then , what is $c$ ?

This is a basic polynomials question, to reach the solution we use derivative for shortcut. For example, we find $P(1) ,P'(1),P''(1)$ respectively. Then answer is $2$..

My question is why we use derivative, I could not conceive the reason behind the usage of derivative. In first thought, I thought that if $(x-1)^3$ divides $P(x)$ , then $(x-1)^2$ and $(x-1)$ divides $P(x)$, as well. However, I could not see any relation with derivative. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593568/multiple-root-of-a-polynomial-is-also-a-root-of-the-derivative)

Comment: The divider has degree $3$, so the quotient must be a constant. Comparing the leading coefficients, you have that $P(x)=2(x-1)^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume a zero of order $p$ for the function $f(x)$.

This implies that we can write $f(x) = (x-x_0)^pg(x)$

Now, look at the derivative.
$f'(x) = p(x-x_0)^{p-1}g(x) + (x-x_0)^pg'(x)$

For $p=2$ we see that the second order zero will result in $f'(x=x_0)=0$.
You can repeat the same logic for higher order zeros.

Comment: this was what i am looking for ,

Answer (score 2):

That is much easier to solve. As degree of $P$ is $3$ $P$ needs to be a constant multiple of $(x-1)^3$. The lead coefficient gives us that this constant factor is $2$ and thus $c=2(-1)^3 = -2$.

But for your question: You can easily proove that $x_0$ is only a double root of a polynomial if it’s also a root of the derivative, and more general, $x_0$ is a root with muliplicity $n$ if and only if it is a root of the derivative of multiplicity $n-1$.

Thus $x-1$ must also be a root of $P'$ and of $P''$. This means that $c$ has to be chosen in such a way, that $(x-1)$ is a common factor of $P,P',P''$.

If we choose $x=1$ then $(x-1)=0$, so
$$ 0=P(1) = 2+2a+b+c$$
$$ 0=P'(1) = 6+4a+b $$
$$ 0=P''(1) = 12+4a $$
Now you could solve this system, i.e. $a=-3$, $b=6$, $c=-2$.

Comment: +1: Well done for making it quite clear that the proposed method for solving this particular problem is not a shortcut: it turns something you can do in your head in the twinkling of an eye into linear algebra drudgery.

Comment: @RobArthan Well, I guess it *can* be useful in other situations, as it turns an divisibility equation in Polynomials into a system of linear equations over the field. Let’s say $P$ was not degree $3$, but degree 10. Then doing an approch $(x-1)^3*Q(x) = P(x)$ would be rather complicated, and dividing $P$ formally by $(x-1)^3$ and equating the rest to $0$ might not be very funny. But evaluating three derivatives and solving a linear system is not that hard.

Comment: thanks for your observation. I was wondering about the case when the original polynomial has a greater degree than the divisor. It seemed to me that the linear system would have more variables than equations. But I can see now that if you were given enough of the coefficients as constants it might save some effort. It seems like a very poor example of the technique.

Comment: Yes, it appears the priciple is very limited. Any root with multiplicity $n$ will give us $n$ equations. If we evaluate the polynomes in a different point than the root we only get a divisor of the result. If we know that all factors are integral polynomials, this could be used to solve equations modulo some $m$ (in our case if $x=4$ then $(x-1)=3$, so we might try so solve modulo $3$.

Comment: @Lazy "more general, x0 is a root with muliplicity n if and only if it is a root of the derivative of multiplicity n−1" , what is the name of this theorem and how can i reach its proof ?

Comment: @webboo A trivial result from the multiplication rule for  differentiation: If $P=(x-x_0)^n Q$ then $P' = (x-x_0)^nQ' + n(x-x_0)^{n-1}Q = (x-x_0)^{n-1}((x-x_0)Q'+nQ)=(x-x_0)^{n-1}R$. As $(x-x_0)| (x-x_0)Q'$ but $(x-x_0)\not| nQ$ we have $(x-x_0)\not| R$, so the multiplicity is exaclty $n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

So, for all $x$ we have $$2x^3 + 2ax^2 +bx +c =k(x-1)^3\;\;\;\;\;\;(\spadesuit)$$ for some constatnt $k$. Clearly we see that if we put in it $x=1$ we get $$2+2a+b+c =0$$
Now let's take a look what happend if we take the derivative of $(\spadesuit)$, we get:

$$6x^2+4ax+b = 3k(x-1)^2\;\;\;\;  (\diamondsuit)$$ which is valid also for all $x$, so in particular, for $x=1$ we get:

$$6+4a+b=0$$ and for the last time, if we again take the derivative of $(\diamondsuit)$ we get: $$12x+4a=6k(x-1)$$ which is again valid for all $x$ and thus also for $x=1$...